# Proxy 404s with Create React App

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, redux, passport.js

I'm getting a stream of 404s when running the dev server with a React app I wrote with create-react-app. I've proxied my NodeJS server so I can avoid cross origin issues with my custom API. However recently when I launch my app I get this:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kEKg.png)

I'm not making any calls to a /json endpoint in my code. Any this only seems to happen when I'm running the dev server for the frontend React portion of my code. Any ideas on what may be happening?

Here's my code on Github: https://github.com/justincrich/career-playbook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/json` is used for reload/hot reload by webpack dev server.
So you should not pass it down to the proxied app server